# How can I Create Drawer menu without Navigation feature?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I need to create the react native drawer without navigator. In drawer I need to display a list of items and need not to navigate.

How can it be possible using react native drawer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are talking about some view which does have some list but it will be shown just like drawer.

Simply create a view which will be hidden by default, whenever user press on menu icon you can show it with some slide animation.

You can take a look at [react-native-reanimated](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated) to check in detail about animations.

You can take reference from this [react-native-side-menu](https://github.com/Kureev/react-native-side-menu) archived library code or from [react-native-drawer](https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer) library, it might be helpful.

I doubt you will find something readymade as per your requirement.